# LINQ Orderby clause is causing weird results

Tags: c#, linq

I have created the following LINQ query to demonstrate the problem:

```
string[] dateStrings = new string[] { "2009-07-20 13:00:00", "2009-07-20 16:00:00", "2009-07-20 09:00:00" };

DateTime dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;    

var results =
    from dateString in dateStrings
    where DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)
    orderby dateValue descending
    select dateValue;
```

You'd expect the result to be a list of DateTimes in the reversed order:
20-7-2009 16:00:00
20-7-2009 13:00:00
20-7-2009 9:00:00

However all I get is this:
20-7-2009 9:00:00
20-7-2009 9:00:00
20-7-2009 9:00:00

What am I doing wrong?
If you remove the orderby statement you'll notice a normal list of DateTime's.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where is dateValue declared?  Observe that it can only hold one value.

Try this instead:

```
string[] dateStrings = new string[] { "2009-07-20 13:00:00",
  "2009-07-20 16:00:00", "2009-07-20 09:00:00" };

var results =
dateStrings.Select(s => 
{
  DateTime v;
  bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse(s, out v);
  return new {Parsed = parsed, Value = v };
})
.Where(x => x.Parsed)
.Select(x => x.Value)
.OrderByDescending(d => d);
```

Comment: Sorry forget to type that in this example. I've updated the question. Without the orderby all is well.

Comment: The orderby must eagerly resolve the query above that point before ordering may proceed.  After all three records have been processed by your where clause, dateValue's value has obtain it's final value.  Then orderby operates and sorts by that one value.  Then select operates and projects that one value 3 times.

Comment: Thnx! I can keep the query the same. However instead of making the orderby part of my Linq query, I can do the ordering just before setting it to my DataSource.

Answer (score 6):

try the method

```
       var results =
            from dateString in dateStrings
            orderby (Convert.ToDateTime(dateString)) descending
            select (Convert.ToDateTime(dateString));
```

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by deferred execution.

`dateValue` can only have one value, which will be the last value in dateStrings.

Read the following article on [Closures](http://diditwith.net/2007/09/25/LINQClosuresMayBeHazardousToYourHealth.aspx) to understand why:

http://diditwith.net/2007/09/25/LINQClosuresMayBeHazardousToYourHealth.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `orderby` clause requires that the `where` clause is executed first. The `orderby` is being applied after the `where` and it needs all it's results to perform the `orderby` operation. Hence `dateValue` will contain always the last *where* result.

Here's a solution:

```
        var results = from date in
                           (
                               from dateString in dateStrings
                               where DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)
                               select dateValue
                           )
                      orderby date descending
                      select date;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the topics on the Start Page of Visual Studio 2008 and noticed a topic about the "let" keyword. This brought me to the solution below:

```
string[] dateStrings = new string[] { "2009-07-20 13:00:00", "2009-07-20 16:00:00", "2009-07-20 09:00:00" };

DateTime dateVal = DateTime.MinValue; 

var results =
from dateString in dateStrings
where DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateVal)
let dateValue = dateVal
orderby dateValue descending
select dateValue;
```

Notice that all I did was add the line and rename the variables accordingly:

```
let dateValue = dateVal
```

Quite simple and effective.

Answer (score 0):

> var results =
>      from dateString in dateStrings
>      where DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dateValue)
>      orderby dateValue descending
>      select dateValue;

I believe that Linq is using delayed execution for the query, but not for the TryParse so you are getting only the last value of the Date from the TryParse when the query actually exectues.

Try moving parsing the dates into an array, then use the appropriate Linq construct to perform your logic against that.